# Changing the scope (value of "this")

Tags: javascript, console, typescript

I'm trying to create a logger that outputs a message and the class it's called from, like this:

```
const __log = (...values: Array<any>) => 
  console.log("%c" + this.constructor["name"], CLASS_STYLE, ...values);
```

This work nicely, but I'd like to keep it DRY, to import it once if possible and call wherever I need to. I was thinking about adding it as `window.__log`, but of course there's an issue with the scope of **this**.

#### What would be the best way to change the scope?

I'm looking for some kind of `bind()`, `call()`, `apply()` trickery/wizardry that would make this work (;

Example planker is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/sLdAsbv8FgO4V1qfqQZM (with Angular2 component). Removing the `// const __log ...` comment in class `App` would show what I want to get.

Comment: In the question you're using ES6 with the arrow notation `(...) => {...}` (which fixates the value of `this` anyway) whereas in the example (plunker) you're using a plain old `function(){...}`. Which version is the "correct" one?

Comment: @Andreas I've been trying different things, see updated plunker. Any solution that works would be the "correct" one (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archive what you want by doing so:

```
function __log(...values: Array<any>)
{
    console.log("%c" + arguments.callee.caller.name, CLASS_STYLE, ...values)
}
```

If you want to go deeper, here is some more info about getting full call stack: [link](http://www.codeovertones.com/2011/08/how-to-print-stack-trace-anywhere-in.html)

Comment: Thanks, this was helpfull. I ended up with something similar (http://plnkr.co/edit/sLdAsbv8FgO4V1qfqQZM) to account for nesting. Your example only works from the constructor.